# MOSFET Overheating when Driving Stepper motor

Tags: mosfet, motor, stepper-motor, fet

I'm trying to create a stepper motor driver for a 5 phase motor based on the application note found [here](http://www.orientalmotor.com/technology/articles/pdfs/BuildingA5PhaseDriver_wDriverOptions.pdf).

So based on this, I am using the following [MOSFETS](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/PHP36N03LT-355073.pdf):

These are hooked up to an Arduino and I'm running code based on the lookup table in the application note from orientalmotor using port manipulation. So for like the first step I'm just setting the gates for various high side FETs high or low and same for the low side FETs.

This setup worked but the high side A phase and E phase MOSFETS got ridiculously hot, like they melted the breadboard hot. This is where I am confused, is there any reason why this could be happening only on these two phases? Could it be that these MOSFETS aren't getting turned on all the way?

As a side note the other MOSFETs do get hot, but they are not burning themselves. Just to give you a reference point, when I used my multimeter to measure the temperature of the MOSFETs that I thought were hot (phase A and E), if I touched the plastic to the back of the MOSFET it melted it.

Comment: How hard are you driving the gates and to what values? Look  up the datasheet what \$R_{DS}(on)\$ values you get for these situations.

Comment: You have made a driver like you think it might work, without reading the whole document. I mean how do you regultate the current in each phase? Or you have simply implemented a look up table that is switcing the mosfets to ouptut almost short circuit current. What about motors, are still alive?

Comment: The gates are being driven with a digital 5 volts on or off (i.e. no pwm). The motor is rated at 1.7 A per phase I believe. The Rds on for that logic level is about 20 mOhm but I'm using a 12 v 10 Amp power supply so could it be that the motor is drawing too much current since its an indicative load? Do I need to make it a chopper circuit?

Comment: The driver does work (not well) but it works. I'm currently not limiting the current to each phase which was my second guess at the problem since motors can't self regulate current draw. I've done the latter of what you said Marko. The motor is fine. I only did limited testing to limit the damage

Comment: @DeveloperPaul: you might be driving them with 5V but that does not necessarily mean that \$V_{GS}\$ is 5V. Without at least some schematics no one can tell. You might want to measure that with your scope.

Comment: The other usual reason for high power dissipation in MOSFETS is how fast - or slow they are switching. If you don't have a powerful enough (high current) gate driver they switch on and off slowly and you get high losses in the FETS during the transitions - this is related to how fast you are making them switch. Are the FETS cool when the motor is held at a steady position?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The schematic is in the application note from oriental motor. I'll have to measure that though and see what is going on.

Comment: @Icy The driver I'm using is an arduino's digital ports. So definitely not a high current gate driver. I'll have to see if the FETs are cool when holding the motor.

Comment: Do you know the coil resistance (&/or voltage rating) of the motor? You say the motor is rated at 1.7A per phase. Have you measured the max phase current when not stepping?

Comment: You must find or measure the DC resistance of a coil before you go any further.

Comment: @Tut I do not, I'll have to measure it when I get the chance. Also the motor is actually rated at 0.75 Amps per phase not 1.7.

Comment: You state "The gates are being driven with a digital 5 volts on or off" and you indicate you are using N-channel MOSFETs. The high-side MOSFETs need a higher gate voltage than the motor supply voltage (12V?) if they are N-channel which is normally done using a high-side driver IC. If using P-channel, the gates still need to go as high as the motor supply voltage in order to turn off. You really should give a drawing of exactly what you have as your descriptions do not match the schematic shown in the app note.

Comment: @Tut Yes that is correct all my MOSFETs are N channel. I'm not sure that the MOSFETs need a gate voltage higher than the supply though. I have implemented exactly what is in the app note with the gates to the 10 mosfets connected to 10 digital pins of my arduino.

Comment: Since the source of your high-side driver is connected to the coil and not directly to GND, Vgs will be less than 5V and your MOSFET is likely not turning fully on causing it to overheat. You need a high-side driver IC (the IC in the app note uses a charge pump to attain the higher voltage). The alternative is to use P-channel and invert your gate logic. Even so, this will not work for motor supply voltage greater than 5V or you will need to level-shift the gate drive for the high-side.

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense, you are absolutely right. So would the UCC27211 be a good high/low driver IC? Or would I still need the higher voltage for the high side even in this configuration?

Comment: The UCC27211 uses a bootstrap capacitor to achieve the higher gate-drive voltage (as do most high-side driver ICs). This can have a problem if you do not use PWM and the motor sits idle. You will likely need to implement PWM anyway in order to regulate your current (see the current-sense resistor in your app note and also see Will Dean's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are driving the MOSFETS direct from the Arduino digital outputs, they are not being turned on hard enough or fast enough. This means that they spend a considerable time in a higher resistance state than they should.

Another problem with the H bridge arrangement you are using given this slow switching speed is that there is a chance that you will get current flowing directly through the high FET and the low FET without ever going through the motor at all.

To fix this you should drive the FETS with a dedicated driver IC's like UCC27211 http://www.ti.com/product/ucc27211 - which will ensure that the FETS are fully driven on and off in the minimum time.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with these ICs. Could you briefly explain how these would mitigate the problem? Based on the data sheet you basically have an input and then an output for high side and low side mosfets. Would I need to change anything on the arduino side before feeding that into the input of the IC? Or could I keep the same configuration and then use this chips as pre drivers?

Comment: Driver IC's will provide both enough volts to fully turn on the FETS and enough current to make sure they are turned on in a very short time. The high side driver in particular generates a voltage that remains above the drain voltage making it easy to use N channel FETS with high switched voltages. Yes, you basically treat them as 'pre-drivers' - just drive the inputs from the Arduino, and the FET gates from the outputs as per the datasheet.

Comment: Ok cool I'll have to give that a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: note: there are lots of different driver options - just look for MOSFET drivers on your favourite supplier. You will probably want  DIP packaged ones for prototyping. They are available in low side, high side, half H and other options, the main thing for you is to make sure the inputs are compatible with your logic signals.

Comment: Ok thanks, basically I need something that can accept 5V logic levels. Is there anything specific I should look at in matching the output of the IC to the MOSFET?

Comment: Not really, you won't be using fantastically high switching speeds, your high side supply (the motor supply) is only 12V and your MOSFET has a fairly low gate charge (effectively input capacitance) so is easy to drive.

Comment: ok thanks. As far as using PWM as per Will Deans answer, how exactly would that work? So currently I'm using just digital high and low signals. With PWM would a high signal just correspond to using a duty cycle that is mostly on and then a low signal would be one that's mostly off. How do you select the duty cycle for these and what effect does the frequency of the PWM signal have?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore inductance and MOSFET stuff for the moment.

If you put 12V across a 20mOhm resistor (actually it's probably two coils in series, so it's 40mOhm), you'll be attempting to supply 300A.

*** Update - I see that it's your MOSFETs are 20mOhm, not the motor.  What's the motor coil DC resistance?  ***

Clearly that's not going to happen, but it should give you some pause for thought.

You really have two choices:

- Use simple unregulated MOSFET switching like you're doing, and set the supply voltage low enough that the motor current is sensible.   You will not be able to go very fast like this, but it will be very simple.
- Use a higher voltage, so that you can drive the motor faster, but have more sophisticated electronics to regulate the current into the motor (e.g. a chopper).  This is what the IC in the app note is doing.

Comment: Actually the coils are technically all in series. There is 5 of them and they are arranged like a pentagon. I think I do need a chopper circuit but I want to do this without using the IC in the app note. Also as far as the motor winding dc resistance, I may have to measure that myself because I can't find it in the specifications oddly enough.

Comment: Well, clearly you don't run them all in series, as you can't get electricity to flow around a loop like that - I see from the datasheet that they run in various series/parallel combinations, for example figure 3 would have an effective resistance the same as one coil.

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: Can you post the spec of the motor?

Comment: Do you  have any good reference notes on making a chopper? Could I use an op amp as a voltage comparator and use that to selectively turn mosfets on/off when the voltage is getting too high and thus limit the current?

Comment: Motor Specs: http://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/all-categories/pk-series-5-phase-stepping-motors/pk544pma#Specifications

Comment: You can create a chopper by modulating the gate drive using a PWM output from your Arduino. This just requires AND gates on all the low side gate drives